# MVC4: On validation error, change the textbox color to red

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form which has some text boxes, and when the textbox doesn't contain valid value I get the error message but the textbox color doesn't change to red.

This is what I have

**Model**

```
public class AddCompany
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Address is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{4})\)?([A-Z]{2})",ErrorMessage = "*Not a valid Zip Code, Must be in format 1234AB")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Phone Number is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{10})", ErrorMessage = "*Not a valid number, must be 10 numbers")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateTimeAdded { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@model CrmTestProject.Models.ViewModels.AddCompany

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddCompany";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>

<h2>AddCompany</h2>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset class="form-horizontal">
    <legend>New Company <small>Add</small></legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddCompany", "Company"))
    {
        <div class ="controls">
            <label class="label">@Html.Label("Name")</label>
            <div class="input-block-label">@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Name)
            </div>
            <br/>
            <label class="label">@Html.Label("Address")</label>
            <div class="input-block-level">@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Address)
            </div>
            <br/>
            <label class="label">@Html.Label("Phone")</label>
            <div class="input-block-level">@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Phone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Phone)
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Comment)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions" id="buttons">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit">Save changes</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "CompanyIndex", new { @class = "btn" })
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

**Browser ScreenShot**
[image]

As you can see I get the error message but I also want the textbox and preferably error message color to be red. I don't know if it is due to bootstrap.
But when I check this [blog for validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/05/new-validation-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-3-future.aspx) things work perfectly here.
Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: In the future, if you want help with JavaScript (client-side code), you need to show the _rendered_ HTML as seen by the browser (client), not the server!  However, this is not any problem with JavaScript or jQuery Validate, but only an issue with your CSS.  Use your DOM inspection tools to see what CSS rules are being applied or over-written, so you know how to correct it.  Hint:  `.error` is the default `class` used by the Validation plugin.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Add a class in css and change its colour like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Address),"*Address is required",new { @class = "redclass" })
```

Comment: This will change the message, not the text box

Answer (score 8):

simply you can add this css code to your style. no need to change any js or your views.

```
input.input-validation-error,
textarea.input-validation-error,
select.input-validation-error
{
    background: #FEF1EC;
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
}
```

Comment: Neat and simple solution.